# For every $x \in A$, $x<5$, there is a number in set $B$ greater than $x$ in mathematical notation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I would like to ask why were my answers wrong. I was supposed to decide which notation has the same meaning as the text (title).

1. $(x<5 \Rightarrow (\exists y \in B)(y>x))$ - This is not correct, because there is not defined that $x$ is from set $A$.
2. $(\forall x\in A)(x<5\land(\exists y\in B)(y>x))$ - This is correct, it is for all x from set $A$, when both $x<5$ and $y>x$ are true, existential quantifier for $y$ from set $B$ is correct either.
3. $(\exists x\in A)(x<5 \lor(\forall y \in B)(y>x))$ - This is not correct, because it is not for every $x$ in set $A$.
4. $(\forall x \in A)(x<5 \Rightarrow(\exists yB)(y>x))$ - I think this is correct, but I said it is not, because $(\exists yB)(y>x)$ is not true just because $x<5$. But I was probably wrong, I am not sure how is it different from 2 in this case.

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Ideally, at some point in the future, a smart search engine will be able to "understand" MathJax and recommend similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, "English" is not Precise, hence both (2) & (4) are Possibly Correct !

Interpretation will change the answer.
What is the meaning of "comma" between "$x \le 5$" & "there is a " in the given "English" Statement ?
If that "comma" is "AND" then (2) is correct.
If that "comma" is "then" then (4) is correct.

In either case , (1) & (3) are not correct.

Here is the Example where (2) is correct :
$A=\{1,2,3\} , B=\{0,8\}$
[ all elements in A are $\le$ 5 **(AND)** those elements have 8 (no worries about 0) in B which is greater ]

Here is the Example where (4) is correct :
$A=\{1,2,3,9\} , B=\{0,8\}$
[ some elements in A are $\le$ 5 **(which then implies that)** those elements (excluding 9) have 8 in B which is greater ]

Which is Correct ?
We have to know what that "comma" means, to Answer that Question !

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I answered: (2) & (4) correct and (1) and (3) wrong, but my answer was wrong again. Any ideas?

Comment: Both (2) **AND** (4) can not be correct. Either (2) **OR** (4) is correct Depending on what the "comma" indicates ! @MagentaBloabner

Comment: The title is translated from a different language, there is not a comma. The meaning is "AND".

Comment: With the "comma" indicating "AND" , (2) is naturally correct & (4) is naturally not correct because "only one Choice" can be correct here ! @MagentaBloabner

Comment: Thats what I thought, so... there is a mistake?

Comment: Not sure what mistake you mean in my Answer ?? @MagentaBloabner

Comment: Well, your answer is probably correct. I mean it is supposed to be (2), so the app the question is from might be wrong?

Comment: App might be wrong OR App might be treating "comma" == "then" !

Comment: Yep, but the meaning is not then in the original language. Thanks for your answer :).